# Looping And Rendering In JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, loops, jsx

I Need To Loop Through An Array-Like Object And Render Components In React Native According To It's Length And The And In It Here Is The Code:

```
  const Screen = function({navigation, route}) {
  var data = [];
  var cases = [];
  axios.get(`${uri}cases`)
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json)
    data = json.data
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  });

  function showCases(cases){
    cases.forEach(one => {
      cases.push(<Text>one._id</Text>)
    })
  }
showCases(data)
var comp = [<Text>Hello</Text>, <Text>Hello</Text>]
  return(
 <View>
  <View>
  <Button title='Click' onPress={() => {
    cases.push(<Text>Hello</Text>)
    console.log(cases)
    console.log(comp)
    console.log(comp == cases)
    }} />
    <Button
          title="Modern Clinic"
          disabled={true}
        />
        <Button title="Profit" onPress={() => {
          navigation.push('Profit')
        }} />
        <Button title="Expenses" onPress={() => {
          navigation.push('Expenses')
        }}/>
        <Button title="New" onPress={() => {
          navigation.push('New...')
        }}/>
      </View>
    <SafeAreaView>
  <ScrollView>
  <Text>{cases}</Text>
  </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
</View>
  )
}
```

I just want to Loop Through The `data` variable And Render Components I just want the logic so rendering a `<Text />` component is okay just The Logic

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `FlatList` which is the most used Component to display `List` in React, It's like a `Foreach`.

Pass your data in the argument data. And in your `renderItem` place your component. In your component, access the value of `foreach` with `{item.Something}`, in this example data are :
`this.state.listParam = {.{"des":"Name","value":"John","mandatory":true, ...} }`

```js
<FlatList
    style={{ marginBottom: 40 }}
    data={this.state.listParam}
    keyExtractor={(item,i) => i.toString()}
    renderItem={({item,index}) => {
        return(
            <HiddenMandatoryInput
                style={ style.textinput }
                placeholder={item.des}
                value={item.value}
                mandatory={item.mandatory}
                visible={item.visible}
                onChangeText={(text) => this._changeText(text, item.name)}
                type={item.type}
            />
        )
    }} 
/>
```

Comment: You Mean That I Have To Use ```<Flat List />```Component And Pass A Data Prop To It Only Or I Need More Than The Data Prop but ok thanks And i will read the docs if i had any more issue i just wanted to Know which component should i use

Comment: I Dont Have To Loop Right I Will Loop For Me

Comment: U need to loop right for you eheh. If you want to know how to use with your api call: in your then() make a setstate({data:data)} , and in flatlist data={this.state.data}  , this is the old version of using react , now u can use the New function of react like usestate who set the state too

Comment: The Problem Is That I Cant Access My State Directly Because I Am Using ```react-native-navigation```

Comment: U need to use navigation.setParam('yourkey',yourValue) to set value in your Navigation, and use navigation.getParam('yourkey') to get value, i think that's a bad way to use navigation, see the doc how to make properly your component : [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation)

Comment: U can only access state in Class, U actually use Hook, refers to doc to use the new Function of React like useState or useEffect